# give info window if gps location not enable in browser

Tags: javascript

to fully function of my website users should enable location in browser, how to remind to users or give info window if in their's  browser not enable location. In most cases there just does not know how to enable or clicking decline sharing location.

Comment: If geolocation isn't available, the object returns an error, see [*MDN: The geolocation object*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation). You can then ask the user to enable it, but plan for them not having it enabled (e.g. by allowing them to enter a city, locality, post code, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below links should help

1 https://github.com/chrisdavidmills/location-finder-permissions-api/blob/gh-pages/scripts/geoMap.js .

2 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions_API/Using_the_Permissions_API

Also if the user accidentally denies for location you can confirm once again by calling your function for another prompt at line#67(of the github geoMap.js).